# ld cannot find udev

Tags: linux, ld

I'm trying to compile a program but it throws the following error:

```
[cc] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
```

I checked other topics on SO but the responses were to install something while I seem to be having libudev installed.

In /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu I also have:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 lut 19 21:30 libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.3.5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67600 lut 19 21:31 libudev.so.1.3.5
```

I've tried linking libudev.so.0 to libudev.so.1 but it's still not working. What is ld looking for and why is it not working? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you use `-lfoo` the linker will look for a file named `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so`.

So in your case, you need `libudev.so` without any suffix number.

Some Linux distributions, such as Debian and derivates (Ubuntu?), do not install these symlinks by default. So instead of creating that symlink yourself, try first looking for the `*-dev` package (`libudev-dev`).

Comment: On Fedora I accomplished this by installing the package `systemd-devel`

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04 I had to do `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libudev-devel` because it was already installed but still had not created these symlinks in `/lib and /usr/lib

Answer (score 2):

`ld` is the command for linker,  you need to update your `LIBPATH` variable to include the library location.

check the value of the env variable LIBPATH and change it to `LIBPATH=LIBPATH:<lib location>` and compile again.

Comment: Is it normal that in default "echo $LIBPATH" gives me nothing? (an empty string)